# VSCode solargraph provider failed on Ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, installation

Can I get Ruby code navigation to work with VSCode and Ruby 2.2.2? I've installed the latest VSCode (1.51.1), but I'm trying to edit code in a project that's still on Ruby 2.2.2. I'm able to get code completion and docs working for built-in classes like `String`, but I can't get it working for code in the project.

To diagnose the problem, I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose `Developer: Show Logs...`, followed by `Extension Host`. Then when I hover over a project method, I see this repeated several times in the output window:

```
[2020-11-30 15:08:33.198] [exthost] [error] [castwide.solargraph] provider FAILED
[2020-11-30 15:08:33.198] [exthost] [error] undefined
```

I've installed three VSCode extensions:

1. Ruby 0.27.0 by Peng Lv
2. Ruby Solargraph 0.12.0 by Castwide
3. VSCode Ruby 0.27.0 by Stafford Brunk

I tried installing newer versions of Solargraph, but their dependencies didn't work on Ruby 2.2.2.

As an experiment, I tried creating a minimal project to navigate through. I see the error above when I open `myproject.rb` and hover over the call to `get_other_name()` on line 5.

#### myproject.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'helper'

get '/' do
    'Hello, ' + get_other_name()
end

def get_name()
    return 'Bob'
end
```

#### helper.rb

```
def get_other_name()
    return 'Alice'
end
```

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'

# To install all these gems, run "gem install bundler", then "bundle install".

gem 'thin', '1.7.2'
gem 'sinatra', '2.0.1'

group :devtools, optional: true do
    gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.52'
    gem 'solargraph', '0.12.2'
end
```

#### .vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "solargraph.useBundler": true
}
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04, and I used `rvm` to install Ruby 2.2.2. I also tried turning off bundler in the solargraph settings and setting the command path to solargraph, but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you checked [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/castwide/vscode-solargraph/issues/74)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @J.M.Arnold, but I didn't find anything helpful there. It seems like `solargraph -v` isn't supported anymore. It says, `Could not find command "_v".`